# Function to run Unit Tests internally

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to write a javascript function to invoke UT internally inside the browser.

1. The function will recieves an array of UT files (written for Jasmine)
2. It will load and then run them
3. It will return their output in a neat object with fields to describe the run: successful / failed specs and reasons.

Can anyone point me to an existing solution?

Comment: in node? in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Jasmine is seperated into three:

1. Jasmine core - which is in `jasmine.js`
2. A Reporter - handles Jasmine's different events: 'jasmineStarted',
     'jasmineDone',
     'suiteStarted',
     'suiteDone',
     'specStarted',
     'specDone'..  the default one is `jasmine-html.js`
3. `boot.js` - which (amongst other things) tie the two together.

So if we want to redirect Jasmine's output, we need to code a new Reporter, and a good seed for that is the [TapReporter](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/master/src/tap_reporter.js), which redirects it to the console.